# JavaFX Path with lines with different stroke width

Tags: path, width, javafx, line, stroke

I'm trying to draw a `Path` object with only lines, but with different stroke widths. Is that possible?

My try:

```
    border.setStrokeWidth(2);
    border.getElements().addAll(mTo, lTop);
    border.setStrokeWidth(5);
    border.getElements().addAll(lRight, lBottom, lLeft);
```

Not a success, the last stroke width is used for the whole `Path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO that is not possible. Use different `Path`s for different stroke styles. Or use `javafx.​scene.​shape.Line`s directly.